# Is it possible to put data in an UI element?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

For example, I have this class

```
  public class Task : DependencyObject
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Duration { get; set; }
        public bool Done { get; set; }

    }
```

And I want to save it on a CheckBox instance. Is it possible to save it whole, or atleast an atribute where I can put an int ?

I need this because when the checkbox is check, I need to know which element was checked.

How I generate the UI :

```
private void pageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = App.Current as App;

    var query = obj.Connection.Table<Task>();

    foreach (var task in query)
    {
        var stackLine = new StackPanel();
        stackLine.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        TextBlock taskName = new TextBlock();
        taskName.Text = task.TaskName;
        TextBlock taskDate = new TextBlock();
        taskDate.Text = " " + task.BeginDate.ToString();
        CheckBox taskDone = new CheckBox();
        taskDone.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(taskChecked);
        if (task.Done == true)
            taskDone.IsChecked = true;
        stackLine.Children.Add(taskDone);
        stackLine.Children.Add(taskName);
        stackLine.Children.Add(taskDate);
        listView.Items.Add(stackLine);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read up about MVVM and XAML. Also decide whether you're working with WPF or UWP. They're different. Finally, I can't understand what you are trying to accomplish here. *"I need to know which element was checked"* -- which element of what? Do you mean you need to know which checkbox was checked? Do you have one checkbox per `Task` and you want to know which `Task` the user checked?

Comment: @EdPlunkett Sorry I am doing an uwp app but I thought wpf is pretty much the same. Yes I have an checkbox per Tasks, but I don't know how to bind some data to this checkbox.

Comment: Please show the XAML you're using to create the list of tasks in the UI.

Comment: WPF is conceptually the same but the specifics differ. A WPF answer will often use classes and properties that don't exist in UWP and vice versa.

Comment: I am using code to generate the UI since I need to do a db request to get it.

Comment: That does not require you to generate UI in C#. Not at all. You need to read up about MVVM, then write a viewmodel in C#, and a View in XAML, then use bindings to populate the UI.

Comment: Can I see the code for the `taskChecked` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be wasting your time generating UI in C#; you should write it in XAML and write a viewmodel. You're doing things the hard way. Long term, I recommend you learn the so-called "right way" to work with XAML. It lets you do a lot of cool things easily and some amazing things with moderate-to-unbearable difficulty.

But you probably aren't going to rewrite your entire application today, and you can kludge what you've got very easily, as below.

When you create the `CheckBox`, set its `Tag` property to the `Task` object that belongs to it:

```
CheckBox taskDone = new CheckBox();
taskDone.Checked += new RoutedEventHandler(taskChecked);
//  Here:
taskDone.Tag = task;
```

In the `taskChecked` method:

```
private void taskChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var cb = (CheckBox)sender;

    //  Here we get the Task back from the Tag property. 
    //  Tag is type Object, so we need to cast this one too. 
    var task = (Task)cb.Tag;

    //  Do stuff with the Task
    task.Done = cb.IsChecked;
}
```